# Typescript: variable type resests to "unknown" even after validation

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I have the following code snippet:

See it in the [Typescript Playground.](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true#code/PTAEBcAsEsGdQMYBsCGt51NAtgBwPYBO4ApgCagBGAnhJCaAG4pLRkrhEB0482+ZAK5ISAKGRp4AUQDqAYVAkAHqQB2ZaYUJFQAb1GhDifKtjhCghJ0IAKXIMqsEobCXQoA5iQBcoM4WhVDwAaUHtHaGcEAR8-c0CPAEo9AyM02EFcEltXdy9EgG5UwwBfUTLREFAAFXpQSWzwUAAzQVUraBMseGjsBJbtbHrVRRVs1RZQVkpCFEJqSrAUdSwmyDQ6Bmb8JCR8AHd+2GgPCfBBQgYjUUDSQmaUBAYAQXRGgHkobOfCDxS0iauXz+BJFNLRMixEFBIoVVrtcCdEYNYgAHmq1CyAD4bLAEPRsChgfEgqFmEhBLE2gBrVQHVShfBfQi+V6wD7Mn5JXwo3hMFiU7o1TEMfRpKDafagABEbRwuBErlUpDI0thi0UK3wzXqb2IogNVQAtCbTUbQABtaF-clsDjcXgAXVAZtdbvdHs97sNYHlRCaul5JQG+CG0tgoZIRumao1fuIoFkCmagxlXC4wEEiKQwBI+wQ0oNt2yDyeoE+9EIAElVNt-kZAVCSR4wUZwCKpFoiHIYgB+YkBGGgA3igLYABCJG2lwAMiQgpBwAA1Fh2xEmftUfA7EjLIrFFyBOdBKCb1SCbCUbKtwx9VTHjxQTvaQg9yGb637tKEpQP0++c9L2vA8fz-SBn27PsB1BcoDXhDoul5FdWDIABlZtcXMXwaTpfYGVAJlKxrbZfArbJiPwRIeT1Pl-CFa160MaJTADRtQniCcpyIEgH0XZC1yRUAAF4WhYdlgxEwjyNrfAvyMMU0iMZizGMSFhJldssgg18YmlLARik6sZNAXsCOZCieA7LsdLU3wAANAltMgAH0ABJdEbHh8BnfAEBYEgAFVcCyV80BIGxEhKOyb0U3lUWtHFw2baVQn8UIPJQVxQghEgSkKA8KnScwClAKpKwYfxoKCEcjGgZobA4ydpx4+cPD41d2HXVRkjokT-B4McIrkwx-BKsrsgqrDQBw+kAEJQH2SBqF7GrDCqO8plaqAmFQASTAPOqbGlO8wL0wIzKImTkgUxTjBY1SGBE46jy28DrLfEgzoM8zjNMwyLJO17tI+0B7PczzOCCkK5DCiKSmc6p3neZzUIACXeAAlapotWxTlIDQGT0gCSLuk7ZhsUqovjCbRHBIIZMHWYL536cqDzSKptNIygACsSCsIVtQgEVQAAchmvDRa4GwACYAFYAHYAEZEnZ2r6v6kQidAVFD3vV7Vdu26JQOUBVDzRN5BsOzpXBzLcr0vzVDpJorz8SB-WyOhllAdzCcfYnEHWWYrGyXFkj2IJZrs7KYnytJCqMdaUF-V7+RQjgkQPKp0y4cogA)

```
// this class is imported by the validator.ts module
class EWC extends Error {
    constructor(public message: string, public code: string) {
        super(message);
    }
}

// The assert function is coming from an external library
// and it has the following signature    
interface AssertOtherArg {
    name: string;
    code: string;
}

function assert<Type>(schema: string, value: unknown, other: AssertOtherArg): asserts value is Type {
    throw "unimplemented";
}
// end of assert


// ------- [string-validator.ts] ----------------------------------------------

// import {assert} from "some-lib";
// import EWC from "../util/ewc"

interface OtherInfo {
    name: string;
    typeErrorCode?: string; 

    trimBeforeLenghtValidation?: boolean;

    minLength?: number;
    minLengthErrorCode?: string;

    maxLength?: number;
    maxLengthErrorCode?: string;
}

function assertValidString(str: unknown, otherInfo: OtherInfo): asserts str is string {
    const {name, trimBeforeLenghtValidation = false} = otherInfo;

    {
        const code = "typeErrorCode" in otherInfo ? otherInfo.typeErrorCode : `invalid_${name.toLocaleUpperCase()}`;
        assert<string>("string", str, {name, code});
    }

    str; // here str: string

    if(trimBeforeLenghtValidation) str = str.trim();

    str; // here str: unknown! why?

    // min length vlaidation
    if("minLength" in otherInfo) {
        const code = "minLengthErrorCode" in otherInfo ? otherInfo.minLengthErrorCode : `${name.toUpperCase()}_TOO_SHORT`;

        const {minLength} = otherInfo;

        // the problem is happening here
        // Error: Object is of type 'unknown'.(2571)
        if(str.length < minLength)
            throw new EWC(`"${name}" cannot be shorter than ${minLength} character(s) long!`, code);
    }

    // maxLength validation
    // ...
}
```

In the `assertValidString` function, I'm doing an assertion that the argument `str` is of type `string`. And you can verify that after the assertion the type of `str` is indeed `string`.

```
assert<string>("string", str, {name, code});

str; // str: string
```

But the problem occurs after this line:

```
if(trimBeforeLenghtValidation) str = str.trim();
```

Now the type of `str` argument is `unknown` and it's causing problems further down the line. For example: when I try to access the `length` property:

```
// Error: Object is of type 'unknown'.(2571)
if(str.length < minLength)
    throw new EWC(`"${name}" cannot be shorter than ${minLength} character(s) long!`, code);
```

I get the error:

> Object is of type 'unknown'.(2571)

I don't understand why this is happening and it seems really weird to me.
I know that I can just apply the **`any` hack** as `str: any` in the function parameter declaration but I really want to understand why this is happening! Please enlighten me about this topic with your Typescript knowledge.

Sorry for my bad English. Thanks in advance <3.

Comment: See the answer to the linked question.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit technical, but in a nut shell when you assign to a variable that has the initial type of `unknown` it will `widen` the type to `unknown`.

It doesn't matter if `TS` could infer the type.

You'll need to do another assertion after doing `str = str.trim()`.

The problem stems from how `TS` `widens` types after an assignment and then `narrows` it back down. In your case after the assignment the potential type is `unknown | string`, but when having `unknown` in an union the final type becomes `unknown` (a union type with `any` being the only exception).